# How to get Bazel to link to ICU as an external dependency?

Tags: c++, bazel, icu

I'm getting two different errors depending on which target I build. I can build //:utils, and //:utils_test, but not //:app. I can't run the tests after building them. I'm on an m1 mac, I'm using bazel from homebrew, and clang from xcode. I'm trying to use build targets from the included BUILD file in icu. I tried creating my own icu.BUILD file to use at first, but couldn't include the files under icu/source/common so I just used theirs. It seems a little weird that I'm missing more symbols in one file than the other.

This is the error I get trying to run `bazel test //:utils_test`.

```
INFO: From Testing //:utils_test:
==================== Test output for //:utils_test:
dyld[15553]: symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZN6icu_738ByteSink15GetAppendBufferEiiPciPi'
================================================================================
Target //:utils_test up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/utils_test
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.275s, Critical Path: 0.20s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 darwin-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
//:utils_test                                                            FAILED in 0.1s
```

This is the error I get trying to run `bazel build //:app`.

```
ERROR: /Users/default/Projects/icu-demo/BUILD:10:10: Linking app failed: (Exit 1): cc_wrapper.sh failed: error executing command (from target //:app) external/local_config_cc/cc_wrapper.sh @bazel-out/darwin_arm64-fastbuild/bin/app-2.params

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox and retain the sandbox build root for debugging
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "icu_73::UnicodeString::toLower()", referenced from:
      ToLower(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&) in libutils.a(utils.o)
  "icu_73::ByteSink::GetAppendBuffer(int, int, char*, int, int*)", referenced from:
      vtable for icu_73::StringByteSink<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>> in libutils.a(utils.o)
  "icu_73::ByteSink::Flush()", referenced from:
      vtable for icu_73::StringByteSink<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>> in libutils.a(utils.o)
  "icu_73::ByteSink::~ByteSink()", referenced from:
      icu_73::StringByteSink<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>::StringByteSink(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*, int) in libutils.a(utils.o)
      icu_73::StringByteSink<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>::~StringByteSink() in libutils.a(utils.o)
  "typeinfo for icu_73::ByteSink", referenced from:
      typeinfo for icu_73::StringByteSink<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>> in libutils.a(utils.o)
  "vtable for icu_73::ByteSink", referenced from:
      icu_73::ByteSink::ByteSink() in libutils.a(utils.o)
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Error in child process '/usr/bin/xcrun'. 1
Target //:app failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.168s, Critical Path: 0.11s
INFO: 2 processes: 2 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

WORKSPACE

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "icu",
    sha256 = "a457431de164b4aa7eca00ed134d00dfbf88a77c6986a10ae7774fc076bb8c45",
    strip_prefix = "icu",
    urls = ["https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-73-1/icu4c-73_1-src.tgz"],
)

http_archive(
    name = "tinytest",
    sha256 = "71f366e680606e18268e6b9673a65c44c9e672f7356a61ffbcd3502c6a8eea0b",
    strip_prefix = "TinyTest-460c9492d927689b9db7f28d8742705dc0bbee62",
    urls = ["https://github.com/headhunter45/TinyTest/archive/460c9492d927689b9db7f28d8742705dc0bbee62.zip"],
)
```

BUILD

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary", "cc_library", "cc_test")

cc_library(
    name = "utils",
    srcs = ["utils.cpp"],
    hdrs = ["utils.h"],
    deps = ["@icu//source/common:platform"],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "app",
    srcs = ["app.cpp"],
    deps = ["utils"],
)

cc_test(
    name = "utils_test",
    srcs = ["utils_test.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "utils",
        "@tinytest",
    ],
)
```

utils.h

```cpp
#include <string>

std::string ToLower(const std::string& text);
```

utils.cpp

```cpp
#include "utils.h"

#include <string>

#include "unicode/unistr.h"

using icu::UnicodeString;
using std::string;

string ToLower(const string& text) {
  UnicodeString ustr = UnicodeString::fromUTF8(text);
  string result;
  ustr.toLower();
  ustr.toUTF8String(result);
  return result;
}
```

utils_test.cpp

```cpp
#include "utils.h"

#include <string>
#include <tuple>

#include "tinytest.h"

using namespace TinyTest;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  TestResults results;

  results += execute_suite(make_test_suite(
      "ToLower(const std::string&)", ToLower,
      {
          make_test("should get an empty string", (string) "", make_tuple("")),
          make_test("should get the same string", (string) "the same string",
                    make_tuple("the same string")),
          make_test("should get a lowercase string",
                    (string) "a lowercase string",
                    make_tuple("A lOwErCaSe StRiNg")),
      }));

  return results.failed() + results.errors();
}
```

app.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "utils.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  string original = "ThIs Is A nOrMaL sTrInG.";

  cout << "original:  " << original << endl;
  cout << "lowercase: " << ToLower(original) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you've already solved the issue, but maybe it will be useful for others who will struggle with that.
The main point is to investigate deeply about the build system of internal dependency (icu in our case). They do not adapt their configs (or I haven't found how to run it correctly) for different releases archives. Taking into account, to run your app, it is not enough to use just "platform" from icu.
I had no time to figure out about what exactly do we need, so I've specified all existing targets. At least, it works :)

WORKSPACE:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "icu",
    strip_prefix = "icu-release-73-1",
    urls = ["https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/archive/refs/tags/release-73-1.zip"],
)
```

BUILD:

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary", "cc_library", "cc_test")

cc_library(
    name = "utils",
    srcs = ["utils.cpp"],
    hdrs = ["utils.h"],
    deps = [
        "@icu//icu4c/source/common:breakiterator",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:bytesinkutil",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:bytestream",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:bytestrie",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:bytestriebuilder",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:canonical_iterator",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:characterproperties",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:chariter",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:edits",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:emojiprops",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:errorcode",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:filterednormalizer2",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:hashtable",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:headers",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:icu_utility",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:loadednormalizer2",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:locale_display_names",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:locresdata",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:normalizer2",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:normlzr",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:parsepos",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:patternprops",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:platform",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:propname",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:propsvec",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:resourcebundle",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:schriter",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:service_registration",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:sort",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:stringenumeration",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:stringtriebuilder",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:ubidi_props",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:ucase",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:uchar",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:ucharstrie",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:ucharstriebuilder",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:ucharstrieiterator",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:ucol_swp",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:ucptrie",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:udata",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:uhash",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:uiter",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:ulist",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:umutablecptrie",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:unames",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:unifiedcache",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:uniset",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:uniset_closure",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:uniset_core",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:uniset_props",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:unistr_case",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:unistr_case_locale",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:unistr_titlecase_brkiter",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:uprops",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:uscript_props",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:uset",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:uset_props",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:usetiter",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:ustack",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:ustr_titlecase_brkiter",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:ustring_case",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:ustring_case_locale",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:utext",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:utrie",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:utrie2",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:utrie2_builder",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:utrie_swap",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:utypes",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:uvector",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:uvector32",
"@icu//icu4c/source/common:uvector64",
"@icu//icu4c/source/i18n:collation",
"@icu//icu4c/source/i18n:collation_builder",
"@icu//icu4c/source/i18n:headers",
"@icu//icu4c/source/i18n:uclean_i18n",
"@icu//icu4c/source/stubdata:stubdata",
"@icu//icu4c/source/tools/gennorm2:gennorm2",
"@icu//icu4c/source/tools/toolutil:collationinfo",
"@icu//icu4c/source/tools/toolutil:denseranges",
"@icu//icu4c/source/tools/toolutil:filestrm",
"@icu//icu4c/source/tools/toolutil:ppucd",
"@icu//icu4c/source/tools/toolutil:toolutil",
"@icu//icu4c/source/tools/toolutil:unewdata",
"@icu//icu4c/source/tools/toolutil:uoptions",
"@icu//icu4c/source/tools/toolutil:uparse",
"@icu//icu4c/source/tools/toolutil:writesrc",
"@icu//tools/unicode/c/genprops:genprops",
"@icu//tools/unicode/c/genuca:genuca"
    ],
)

cc_binary(
    name = "app",
    srcs = ["app.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "utils"
    ]
)

cc_test(
    name = "utils_test",
    srcs = ["utils_test.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "utils",
        "@tinytest",
    ],
)
```